# Android app crash on taking picture from camera on nexus

Tags: android, camera

app crashes when we i click Ok on the image taken from camera. issue exists for google nexus devices, works fine for other devices

Error log

```
11-12 14:25:30.059: E/AndroidRuntime(5386): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.pocketbookkeeper/com.pocketbookkeeper.Photo_New_Entry}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Code to start camera activity

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1888);
```

Code for retrieving data from camera activity

```
Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
```

Here this line imageReturnedIntent.getData() returns null. Please note that this happens only when I am using google nexus devices.

Answer (score 0):

The image is returned in the extras with a key of "data", not in the **data** part of the `Intent`. Get it like this:

```
Bundle extras = imageReturnedIntent.getExtras();
mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
```